# Which part will save time if training neural network using GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, deep-learning

There are many work for training a deep neural network using GPU. From optimization perspective, which part saves time? Objective function evaluation? Gradient calculation? or something else? And and why?

Is Certain matrix operations (say matrix multiplication) faster in GPU than CPU?

In [convex optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) Appendex C. We have flops count for each operation. In GPU are these changed? or GPU has much fast flops operations.

[image]

Comment: Your suspicion is correct -- GPUs are great at matrix multiplication.

Comment: Also I would guess "matrix-free" matrix multiplication would be common. By this I mean cases where the "matrix" is very sparse (e.g. convolution) and/or has repeated regular structure (e.g. FFT), it will never be explicitly assembled in practice. Here, algorithms will be structured to access the matrix only through a specialized routine for "matrix-vector multiplication".

Comment: @GeoMatt22, could you give me some example for how fft is related to matrix multiplication?

Comment: @hxd1011 nobody (outside of a classroom or derivation) will do a DFT as a matrix multiplication in practice. However if take the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Definition_and_speed): $X_k=\sum_nx_ne^{-i2\pi kn/N}$, this is a matrix multiplication, $X_k=\sum_n\Omega_{kn}x_n$, where $\Omega_{kn}=\omega^{kn}$ and $\omega=e^{-2\pi i/N}$. Similarly convolutions can be expressed mathematically as multiplication by a (sparse, banded) [matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/convmtx.html), but this is not commonly done (outside of implicit methods for PDEs).

Answer (score 1):

You are right,GPUs, compared to CPUs (Central Processing Unit), are more specialized at performing matrix operations and other advanced mathematical transformations. GPUs obtain such a speed in operations because of the parallel/distributed architecture with many low-end processing nodes.

Answer (score 1):

It's because neural networks are easy to parallel, for common network layers, the same operations are applied to the input and parameters, and the order of executing these operations doesn't affect the output.

GPUs are good at parallel processing as they have thousands of cores. AFAIK the GPU doesn't reduce the number of flops required for matrix operations compared with the CPU.

If a layer involves some operation that doesn't gain much from parallel processing (say the insertion sort), then using GPUs won't be so fast.

Comment: This makes sense broadly. However I imagine there must also be some constraints on data movement (e.g. considerations like [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5762730/))?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Right, I know data movement is important for both GPU and CPU computations, and much acceleration can be gained just by manipulating memories/caches back and forth in a clever way. However I'm not sure exactly what should the constraints be here?

Comment: Generally the same as other memory-hierarchy type issues (e.g. cache-friendly BLAS). If all computations cannot be done on the GPU, then the GPU vs. CPU speedup must be large enough to offset costs associated with data movement between GPU and CPU (basically a version of [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)). I am not familiar enough with GPUs or neural networks to say what the particular constraints might be.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 thanks I got the point, I'll see if I can add some such constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks are in general based on linear algebra computations. If you think about graphics operations like combining two textures (bitmaps), or changing somehow each pixel of texture, what GPUs are built for, it's nothing more and nothing less than simple matrix / vector operations.

Going deeper - GPU is processor that has thousands of computation units with different data registers and common command register, so for example, operation like:

```
X = X + 1
```

Where X is large matrix can utilize every single core of GPU as long as there is only single command to be run of each of them.
How particularly those features are use depends on software, usually linear algebra library / tool like for example Matlab or nVidia DNN libraries.